# Copy multiple values from multiple rows into one cell based on variable condition

Tags: excel, vba

As the topic reveals, I am trying to copy data from multiple cells and rows based on a variable condition. My input looks like this:

```
product size    type     length shoulder  
82HTHSG S       shirt    69     38.5      
82HTHSG M       shirt    74     39.5      
82HTHSG L       shirt    74     41.5      
82HTHSG XL      shirt    77     43       
84HTFSG S       tShirt   66     41        
84HTFSG M       tShirt   67.5   41        
84HTFSG L       tShirt   70     44.5     
84HTFSG XL      tShirt   73.5   46
```

I would like to combine data from all sizes within a product(variable) to a string in a column. It should look like this (ex):

```
product size    type     length shoulder  result
82HTHSG S       shirt    69     38.5      Shoulder x 
                                          Length 
                                          - S  (69cm x 38.5cm)
                                          - M  (74cm x 39.5cm)
                                          - L  (Xcm x Xcm)
                                          - XL (Xcm x Xcm)  
82HTHSG M       shirt    74     39.5      Shoulder x 
                                          Length 
                                          - S  (69cm x 38.5cm)
                                          - M  (74cm x 39.5cm)
                                          - L  (Xcm x Xcm)
                                          - XL (Xcm x Xcm)   
(etc)
```

So far I have written the following code:

```
Sub CombineText()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

If Cells(i, 5) = "shirt" Then

Cells(i, 22).Value = "Shoulder x" & Chr(10) & "Length" & Chr(10) & _
" - " & Cells(i, 3) & " (" & Cells(i, 9) & "cm x " & Cells(i, 16) & "cm)"
i = i + 1

ElseIf Cells(i, 5) = "tShirt" Then

Cells(i, 22).Value = "Shoulder x" & Chr(10) & "Length" & Chr(10) & _
" - " & Cells(i, 3) & " (" & Cells(i, 9) & "cm x " & Cells(i, 16) & "cm)"
i = i + 1

Else

Cells(i, 22).Value = 2
i = i + 1

End If

Loop

End Sub
```

The code gives the following result (ex):

```
82HTHSG S       shirt    69     38.5      Shoulder x 
                                          Length 
                                          - S  (69cm x 38.5cm)
82HTHSG M       shirt    74     39.5      Shoulder x 
                                          Length 
                                          - M  (74cm x 39.5cm)
```

Any thoughts on how I can copy the data from the rest of the sizes within the same product, and paste it all in adjacent cells in a column?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your macro you are missing something like a cycle to go through all the lines of one product code to gather all the data. Below is my code that checks if you found a different product code than in previous line and if yes, it goes through the following lines with the same product code to get all the data necessary.

```
Sub CombineText()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim result As String
i = 2

    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        'check if you are on first line mentioning new product code
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then

            If Cells(i, 5) = "shirt" Then
                result = "Shoulder x" & Chr(10) & "Length" & Chr(10)
                j = i

                'loop through following lines until you reach different product code
                While Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                    result = result & " - " & Cells(j, 3) & " (" & Cells(j, 9) & "cm x " & Cells(j, 16) & "cm)" & Chr(10)
                    j = j + 1
                Wend

            ElseIf Cells(i, 5) = "tShirt" Then
                result = "Shoulder x" & Chr(10) & "Length" & Chr(10)
                j = i

                'loop through following lines until you reach different product code
                While Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                    result = result & " - " & Cells(j, 3) & " (" & Cells(j, 9) & "cm x " & Cells(j, 16) & "cm)" & Chr(10)
                    j = j + 1
                Wend

            Else
                result = 2

            End If

            'fill in the first line for given product code
            Cells(i, 22).Value = result

        'for second and additional lines of the same product there is already correct result in previous line so just copy it
        Else
            Cells(i, 22).Value = Cells(i - 1, 22).Value

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

btw I moved your starting i from 1 to 2, because otherwise it would try to check value of line zero and result in error.

I am not sure why you divided it based on "shirt" and "tshirt", because I dont see any difference in your code, but I kept it just in case I missed something or you need it for something else. Hope it helps

Pavel